# Find the nature of $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty (\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n})^\alpha \ln \frac{n + 1}{n - 1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find whether the following series converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n = 2}^\infty (\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n})^\alpha \ln \frac{n + 1}{n - 1}$$

By graphing the sum, it seems that it converges if and only if $\alpha \gt 1$. I thought that Dirichlet's Criterion is the most suitable for this series, because $\ln \frac{n + 1}{n - 1}$ is decreasing and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln \frac{n + 1}{n - 1} = 0$. But $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty (\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n})^\alpha$ seems to be divergent regardless of $\alpha$, so I can't use this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$, implying
$
 (n+1)^{-1/2} <2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} )<  n^{-1/2}
$. Further, $\log((n+1)/(n-1)) = \log(1+2/(n-1)$; using Bernoulli's inequality we have $e^x\approx  1+x$ for small $x$, so we can compare to $2/(n-1)\approx 2/n$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: An earlier version of this post incorrectly claimed you could use Dirichlet's Test; the logs don't telescope as I'd hoped. I believe this is correct.

Comment: I don't understand where do you use $e^x \approx 1 + x$. If you replace $2 / (n - 1)$ with $e^{2 / (n - 1) - 1}$ you get $e^{(3 - n) / (n - 1)}$. What do you do with that?

Comment: If you buy $e^x\approx 1+x$, taking logs we have $x\approx \log(1+x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$(\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n})^\alpha \ln \left(\frac{n + 1}{n - 1} \right)= (\sqrt{n})^{\alpha}\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}} - 1\right)^\alpha \ln \left(1 +\frac{2}{n - 1} \right)$$
$$ \sim (\sqrt{n})^{\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^\alpha\frac{2}{n-1} = \frac{2}{(2\sqrt{n})^{\alpha}(n+1)} \sim \frac{2^{1-\alpha}}{n^{1+\frac{\alpha}{2}}}$$

So the series converges iff $1+\frac{\alpha}{2} > 1$, i.e. iff $\alpha > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\left(\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n}\right)^\alpha =\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}}\right)^\alpha\sim \frac1{n^\frac \alpha 2} $$

and

$$n\ln \left(\frac{n + 1}{n - 1}\right)=n\ln \left(1+\frac{2}{n - 1}\right) \to 2$$

therefore

$$(\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n})^\alpha \ln \left(\frac{n + 1}{n - 1}\right) \sim \frac1{n^{1+\frac \alpha 2}}$$

and we can determine the convergence by limit comparison test.